# Una funcion que se ejecute exactamente despues de otra

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

```js
export const getProducto=(id, callback)=>{
    fetch(`${Urlbase}/${id}`)
    .then((httpResponse)=>
    {
        if (httpResponse.ok) {
            return httpResponse.json()
        }
    })
    .then(body=>{
        callback(body);
    })
}
export const renderProducto=(json)=>{
    let nombre=json.nombre
    let img=json.image
    let marca=json.marca
    let precio=json.precio
    _root.innerHTML+=displayProducto(img, nombre, marca, precio);
}export const displayCarrito= (id, img, nombre, precio)=>
    `
    <div class="container" id="carrito_producto">
        <img id="img-producto" src="${img}" alt="">
        <label id="nombre-producto">${nombre}</label>
        <label id="precio-producto">${"$"+precio}</label>
        <button id='btnSumar${id}' type="button">+</button>
        <button id="btnRestar${id}" type="button">-</button>
        <input id='impCantidad${id}' type="number" min=0 minLength=1 value=0 placeholder="" readonly></input>
        <button id="btnAgregar${id}" type="button">Agregar</button>
        <button id="btnEliminar${id}" type="button" hidden>Eliminar</button>
        </div>`
```

La funcion `carrito()` despliega toda una lista de productos con sus respectivos botones.

La funcion `siguiente()` agrega eventos a esos botones, por lo que necesito que `siguiente()` espere a que `carrito()` termine de ejecutarse por completo, sino todos los botones me aparecen como `null`.

Con la función `botonn()` lo pude solucionar provisoriamente.

Clickeo un botón como para "actualizar" y que se pueda ejecutar `siguiente()` despues de haber ejecutado `carrito()` pero no es una buena solución.

```javascript
export const mostrarCarrito = () => {
    document.getElementById("divProductos").innerHTML = ""
    document.getElementById("divCarrito").innerHTML = ""
    let contador = 1
    while (contador <= 10) {
        getProducto(contador, renderCarrito)
        contador++
    }
}
var contador = 1
const siguiente = () => {
    while (contador <= 10) {
        const btnSumar = document.getElementById(`btnSumar` + contador)
        const btnRestar = document.getElementById(`btnRestar` + contador)
        const text = document.getElementById(`impCantidad` + contador)
        const btnAgregar = document.getElementById(`btnAgregar` + contador)
        const btnEliminar = document.getElementById(`btnEliminar` + contador)
        btnAgregar.addEventListener("click", () => btnEliminar.removeAttribute("hidden"))
        btnEliminar.addEventListener("click", () => btnEliminar.setAttribute("hidden", "hidden"))
        btnSumar.addEventListener("click", () => text.value++);
        btnRestar.addEventListener("click", () => {
            text.value--;
            if (text.value < 0) { alert("La cantidad no puede ser negativa") }
        })

        contador++
    }
}
const carrito = () => {
    botonCarrito.addEventListener("click", mostrarCarrito)
}
const botonn = () => {
    document.getElementById("boton").addEventListener("click", siguiente)
}
export const IndexRender = () => {
    mostrarProducto()
    filtrarProducto()
    carrito()
    botonn()
}
```

Comment: Por otro lado, no vemos lo que es la función "mostrarCarrito".  Si fuera una petición asincrona (ajax) entonces mejor que pongas la función `siguiente` dentro del success de dicha petición, justo después de desplegar la lista con los botones que explicas.

Comment: Ahi lo corregi, el metodo mostrarCarrito() no es asincronico

Comment: Hummm huele a mala organización del código y/o no uso de las herramientas adecuadas para solucionar este problema. ¿Por qué necesitas agregar cosas a posteriori a los elementos, después de haber sido creados y qué quieres lograr con esas cosas que agregas a posteriori? Trata de explicar el problema en modo puro, olvidándote del código. A veces, sacrificamos el problema, viéndolo desde un código mal concebido teniendo entonces por un lado el problema original y por otro lado ese código mal concebido, que es un problema añadido, resultando en un rompecabezas.

Comment: vaya, seguimos teniendo el mismo problema... ahora no sabemos lo que es la función **getProducto** ni lo que es **renderCarrito** :-S.  Léete [example] para aprender lo que necesitamos aquí como ejemplo válido para poder ayudarte

Comment: Ahi agrege todas las funciones que se usan

Comment: vaya, pues ahí está el problema... sí que usas peticiones asíncronas en getProducto, por eso no siguen el orden que pretendes... creo que en estos casos se usa async/await para controlar mejor la ejecución de las funciones que pretendes en este tipo de llamadas. Te remito a [su documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) para ello, pues no es un tema que yo controle demasiado aún